# Testing extension in Vscode. Unable to read file

Tags: pytest, vscode-extensions, python-3.9

I am currently working on a project that uses python. And I'm facing an annoying problem. I installed the "Testing" extension of Vscode to be able to use pytest directly in vscode. However, in the part I'm working on right now, it's impossible to launch the debugger from the extension. When I select one of the tests of this file or when I try to launch the debugger on one of these tests or when I try to open this file from the extension, this one always returns me the same message.

**how it happens :**

[image]

**Error message**

[image]

This is quite strange since the other tests in the file do not have any problem. I already had a similar problem. I had deleted the .vscode at the time and reloaded the project. That solved my problem for the tests that didn't pass at the time. I did a lot of research. I tried to reload the project folder without success. I found some forums that talked about a task.json file to modify but it seemed more adapted for C++.

Does anyone have any information? I would really like to be able to work on vscode for my internship. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try copying an existing, working test file, then replace its content with the problem test content.

I've seen IDE's get messed up on specific files before, VSCode included - perhaps the file is corrupted in some obvious manner.